# open camera on button click react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, expo

I have the following ReactNative Expo on Snack here

https://snack.expo.io/@viewshub/basic-camera-usage

I am struggling to figure out how to make it work on a button click. I am new to React.

So what I am looking for, is a View with a Button element, that simply calls this function "App" that opens the camera. Just a working example using this code.

I have tried so much stuff and failed on every occasion. I just can not code it. Or get my head around it!

It will help my understand it better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this tutorial, I think it's easier and more intuitive.

https://www.codementor.io/@foysalit/building-a-camera-app-with-react-native-r8up5685v

Comment: Hi Michel thanks for your answer. I am not trying to build a camera app though. I am just trying to fire an event when the button is clicked to call upon the camera. Should be simple stuff. But I am struggling with it. It is just to prove a concept (to someone) that I can fire an event to open the camera...